# When can chrome.tabs.executeScript give an empty array as the result value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am injecting a script to a web page via chrome.tabs.executeScript (at document_end). I am sure the script is syntactically OK and the permissions in the manifest are OK. Most of the time (>99%) everything is fine, the script does what it should and returns what it should.

Sometimes however the result (obtained via the callback) is an empty array. When could that happen?

I noticed that I call the executeScript API while the tab is still loading (but again, most of the time it works). And if I keep retrying to inject the same script again and again, eventually, after a coulple of retries, it returns what it should. But I don't know how to tell if the failed attempts got executed or just failed to return anything.

Edit:
Here's a code example:

```
var debugInjectResultProblem = function(tabId, callback) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: 'Date.now()', runAt: 'document_end'}, function(result) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error('Real error: ', chrome.runtime.lastError);
            callback();
            return;
        }
        console.log('Result is ', result);
        if (!result || result.length === 0) {
            debugInjectResultProblem(tabId, callback);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    })
};

//... the tab gets reloaded here with different URLs couple of times
//... now inside a tab updated event handler
//... the code variable normally contains the script which is quite long
//... but the problem happens even if I do:

code = 'Date.now()';
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: code, runAt: 'document_end'}, function(retVal) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error('Error executing script: ' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    }
    else if (!retVal || !retVal[0]) {
        console.error('Unexpected executeScript retVal: ' + JSON.stringify(retVal));
        debugInjectResultProblem(tabHandle, function() { console.log('Done'); });
    }
    else {
        console.log('OK, result is:', retVal[0]);
    }
});
```

Again, 99% of the time it's OK. Then suddenly the output goes like this:

```
Unexpected executeScript retVal:  []
Result is  []
Result is  []
Result is  [1421783140122]
Done
```

Comment: It could be useful to provide us with any code? We could guess but it is not about guessing.

Comment: The list of results is rarely an empty array. The result list being empty usually indicates a race condition or a bug in Chrome. Could you edit your question and show the code and instructions that trigger this bug?

Comment: Ok, sorry to everybody who OT'ed this for me not giving a code example. My code is rather lengthy. I tried to shorten it, however I was not able to reproduce the behavior. That's why I just asked the general question if [] can be returned for whatever reason. Thanks rob-w for the reply. Others, sorry again.

Comment: Voted for reopen, but I think @RobW needs to look at it.

Comment: Oh, I can think of a reason. What if the tab navigates away before `document_end` fires?

Comment: Could be. Does that explain, however, that the empty array is returned multiple times in a row? I doubt the tab navigates multiple times. But I'll give it a try to reproduce such situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Chrome 41.0.2223.0, you should not get an empty list any more, because the way that content scripts are scheduled was changed in [crbug.com/416907](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=416907#c6) to fix a bug.

Up until Chrome 41.0.2222.0, `chrome.tabs.executeScript` could invoke the callback with an empty list of tabs in the following scenario:

1. A new document has been [committed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCommitted) but not completely loaded yet.
2. `chrome.tabs.executeScript` is called (while the document has not finished loading).
3. The document load at step 1 is aborted *and* a different page is committed.

Comment: @Xan It's not an 1 out of 3 choice, all three have to occur, in that sequence.

Comment: Whoops - but then I really guessed it. QA senses tingling.

Comment: Yes! My logs from the extension confirm that bit about the aborted load and a different page. Thanks a lot.